# How can I wrap a multi-line quote in GFM?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Markdown has this great feature to wrap a bunch of quote between three backticks (```` ``` ````) to open the wrap and another three to close it. The content between those can span several lines and even include blank lines. Everything will be preserved.

Is there an equivalent for the quote that doesn't require me to add `>` in front of every line I want to wrap?

Something like `>>>` to start the wrap quote and `>>>` to close it again?

Comment: Note that the triple-backtick code delimiters are not a *standard* feature of Markdown, but only exist in something like Github-flavoured-Markdown.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you use line breaks (two spaces at the end of every line except the last) instead of paragraphs, you only need one `>`:

```
> Lorem[space][space]
ipsum[space][space]
dolor sit amet
```

Result:

> Lorem
> ipsum
> dolor sit amet

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as I hoped it would on SO

Comment: So to be clear for everyone else.. use two spaces and add a CR, and not just a carriage return(CR) at the eol to get the Block effect word wrapping with a <br />. GFM always inserts a <br /> when two spaces are left at the end of the line even with a normal paragraph.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `<blockquote>` tags for multi-line quotes.

```
<blockquote>
This is one paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
</blockquote>
```

It will appear as:

> This is one paragraph.
>
> This is another paragraph.

Comment: This is the easiest of the [mostly?] universally supported approaches

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `kramdown`, you can use break **`<br>`** or multiple **`<br><br>`** break tag. As you know, the break tag inserts a single line break.

> Lorem`<br>`ipsum`<br><br>`dolor sit amet

Result:

> Lorem
>   ipsum
>
> dolor sit amet

Comment: In Gatsby, `<br />` tag does the job and not [space] as listed in the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643701/5569979) answer.

Comment: Nice answer, it's funny that to illustrate your answer, you used a [technique from a different answer (two spaces followed by a linebreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643701/1175496)

Answer (score 9):

As of now, GFM supports this syntax for multiline blockquote at least in [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#multiline-blockquote).

```
>>>
Testing multiline blockquoute

First line

Second line
>>>
```

Comment: But this doesn't work in GitHub, does it? ([GFM typically represents GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/), although looks like GitLab also uses the acronym GFM)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `>` as part of the output that I wanted to preserve. I used `<br/><br/>` and `&nbsp;`, like this:

```markdown
>Welcome to the Sphinx 4.1.1 quickstart utility.
<br/><br/>
Please enter values for the following settings (just press Enter to
accept a default value, if one is given in brackets).
<br/><br/>
...
<br/><br/>
&nbsp;> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
```

Which resulted in this:

> Welcome to the Sphinx 4.1.1 quickstart utility.
>
> Please enter values for the following settings (just press Enter to
> accept a default value, if one is given in brackets).
>
> ...
>
>  > Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y

This worked with gitlab. Not tested in github. There were places where I didn't want as much white-space between the lines, but I had to just accept it, as `<br/>` did not do the expected job without another break immediately following.

`>>>` did not work, as it swallowed the `>`'s in the quote.